# Displaying data from an array of objects inside document

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

Been trying to take specific data from an array of objects that for many reasons I cannot host on a server. The data is in stored as a variable in the document. This is what i've been trying so far to no success:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">     
        var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]

        var simpson = users.find("last_name" + "Simpson")

        document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = function myfunction() {
            simpson;
        }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="return"></div>
</body>
```

For now I've just been trying to extract some/any data from the 'users' array, but going forward i would like to have the user search for a word and the entire 'line'/'lines' of data related to the word/words in 'users' display as results. What methods should i use to achieve this?

Comment: Question is unclear, do you want to search in `users` array?Please explain properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code. First of all, `find` function accept as argument a `callback` function.

```
 var simpson = users.find(a=>a.last_name=="Simpson");
```

If you pass function to `innerHTML`, you must to invoke it, like this:

```
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = (function myFunction(){
     return JSON.stringify(simpson);
})();
```

and function must return  a `value` in order to set the HTML content (inner HTML) of `result` element.

```js
var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]

var simpson = users.find(callback);
function callback(item){
    return item.last_name=="Simpson";
}
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = (function myFunction(){
     return JSON.stringify(simpson);
})();
```

```html
<body>
<div id="return"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai Thanks! I'm having some trouble with the code though. Dreamweaver is saying there is an error on this line: `var simpson = users.find( a=>a.last_name == "Simpson");`

Comment: Syntax error. I'm not sure how to analyse deeper than that.

Comment: could this somehow be the problem? `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` wondering if my header is wrong... (i've herd in the past that i'm using some out of date stuff.)

Comment: @gezer4000, i updated my answer with `callback` function separated.

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai Unfortunately this is still not working... nothing is displaying on my HTML doc. code snippet is working. is it perhaps an issue with the encoding?

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai Fixed it. Diddnt realise the script had to be placed after the HTML body elemnt. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You  need to pass the `callback` function in `find` method. The `find` method searches for an element in an array and returns the element if it is found. Otherwise `undefined` is returned. The Search Criteria is defined by a callback function. Something like

`var simpson = users.find(currentValue => currentValue.last_name === "Simpson");`

**2.** You might not require your innerHTML to be a function, instead it would be more appropriate that it points to meaningfull information like UserName Found.

`document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = simpson.username;`

Try the following code.

```js
var users = [{"username":"nphillips7m","first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Phillips","email":"nphillips7m@ebay.co.uk","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Networked static concept","language":"Gagauz"},
{"username":"esimpson7n","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Simpson","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Future-proofed solution-oriented definition","language":"Malay"},
{"username":"llawrence7o","first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"llawrence7o@technorati.com","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Re-contextualized demand-driven middleware","language":"Tetum"}]

        var simpson = users.find(currentValue => currentValue.last_name === "Simpson");

        document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = simpson.username;
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">     
        
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="return"></div>
</body>
```